# How to format axis in highchart

Tags: vb.net, highcharts

I am creating a simple chart using the HighCharts .Net API:

```
Dim sFontFamily As String = "fontFamily: 'inherit'"

            Dim oChart As DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts = New DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("SearchCount")
            With oChart
                .InitChart(New DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Chart With {.Style = sFontFamily, .Height = 250, .DefaultSeriesType = DotNet.Highcharts.Enums.ChartTypes.Line})
                .SetOptions(New GlobalOptions With {.Global = New DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Global With {.UseUTC = False}})
                .SetTitle(New Title With {.Style = sFontFamily, .Text = "Search Count"})
                .SetXAxis(New XAxis With {.Labels = New XAxisLabels With {.Style = sFontFamily}, .Title = New XAxisTitle With {.Style = sFontFamily, .Text = "Month"}})
                .SetYAxis(New YAxis With {.Labels = New XAxisLabels With {.Style = sFontFamily}, .Title = New YAxisTitle With {.Style = sFontFamily, .Text = "Searches"}})
                .SetCredits(New Credits With {.Enabled = False})
                .SetTooltip(New Tooltip With {.Style = sFontFamily})
                .SetSeries(New Series() With {.Name = "this year", .Data = New Data(oData)})

                'display a legend so user knows what graphs represent
                .SetLegend(New Legend With {.Style = sFontFamily, .Enabled = True})

                litHighChartSearchCount.Text = oChart.ToHtmlString()
            End With
```

For convenience here is the rendered result: https://jsfiddle.net/d063mhoL/

And the data passed to the Series looks like this:

[image: HighCharts Data]

If you check the Fiddle you will see the data on the Y-Axis is numeric, when I want it to be a string of the month name, can anyone help?

Comment: Better is using datetime type of yAxis, then for each point timestamp (time in milisecond) and format labels by http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats

Answer (score 0):

I needed to set the categories for the axis, like so:

```
.SetXAxis(New XAxis With {.Categories = sCategories.ToArray, .Labels = New XAxisLabels With {.Style = sFontFamily}, .Title = New XAxisTitle With {.Style = sFontFamily, .Text = "Month"}, .Type = AxisTypes.Datetime})
```

sCategories is a `list(of string)` containing the months